# Comparison Flutter GetIt vs GetX

Tags: flutter, get, injectable

as I have read article and find out about dependency injection, I found 2 most popular library for dependency injection.

1. [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) with [Injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable)
2. [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

I know that GetX library is usefull for Routing, State Management too. But in this comparison, I want to focus on depedency injection. Has anyone tried to compare those things? Which is better for performance, advantages and disadvantages about that?